# How can I hide exposed countersunk screws in kitchen cabinets side panel?

Tags: wood, kitchens, cabinets

How do I hide screws on the side of a kitchen cabinet wall that has slightly countersunk screws?  I will be painting my cabinets black.

[image: kitchen cabinets before and after with countersunk screws]

Answer (score 6):

You can use [wood filler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001E5L19O) if you're painting the cabinets. Use a putty knife to apply, and then sand even after it dries.

[image]

Alternatively, if you're going to stain the cabinets, you can use a [plug cutter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DSY5MC) that matches the countersink diameter. Using matching scrap wood, cut a plug that has a similar grain pattern, and lightly tap it in the hole after applying a thin layer of wood glue. When it dries, you can use a chisel to cut it flush or nearly flush, and then finish up with sandpaper. Then you're ready to stain!

[image]

If I remember correctly, [this 5/16" diameter plug cutter](http://www.lowes.com/pd_299839-67702-728005.0_0__?productId=1208831#BVRRWidgetID) works well with a [#8 countersink](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000225OW) hole. (You may want to check, it's been a while since I used that combination on a project.)

Comment: veneer would also work, though may be overkill if you're just painting the cabinet.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a DIY genius, but I'd go with "filler".

Comment: This would make sense as a comment, but still doesn't add much info. Some people might make a comment to @Doresoom such as *+1 for the filler suggestion* and upvote it to show your approval.

Comment: I know... but its like asking "how do I fold paper"

Comment: @DarkcatStudios, The question may have seemed simple enough to you, but trivializing the OP's question doesn't help them out any. It wasn't a stupid question, just an easy one for most people who have a little experience with home repair/woodworking. Isn't that the whole point of this site? To impart our DIY knowledge/experience to others?